# Load JSON file using node require and absolute path fails

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to require a JSON file using `require`. But it fails miserably though the file does exist. I'm wondering if it's because I try to load a JSON file instead of a JS file there, as I usually do.

```
error: verbose: Evaluating c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\config/locales/languages.json as module "c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\config/locales/languages.json" failed with error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

It seems that it doesn't like the `:` character in the windows path. What solution do I have here? I cannot use a relative path to the file because it's a shared file that is loading a file that depends on the application config.

```
var pathLanguages = __config.path.base + __config.path.languages;
var languages = require(pathLanguages + 'languages.json');
```

I believe loading JS file using this method would work. (I've just made the test and it does work with JS file)

Using node 0.10.24

JSON file:

```
{
    "fr": {
        "min": "fr",
        "lang": "fr-fr",
        "language": "Français"
    },
    "en": {
        "min": "en",
        "lang": "en-en",
        "language": "English"
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
error: Error: Evaluating c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\config/locales/fr.json as module "c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\config/locales/fr.json" failed with error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Function.req.load (c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:2505:23)
    at Function.req.get (c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:2455:29)
    at localRequire (c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1632:40)
    at c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\shared\app\Lang.js:36:48
    at forOwn (c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.js:2105:15)
    at Function.forEach (c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.js:3302:9)
    at Function.Lang._loadAllLanguages (c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\shared\app\Lang.js:34:15)
    at Object.module.exports.bootstrap (c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\config\bootstrap.js:28:12)
    at Sails.runBootstrap (c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\bootstrap.js:46:27)
    at Sails.bound [as runBootstrap] (c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.js:729:21) { [Error: Evaluating c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\config/locales/fr.json as module "c:\wamp\www\Ayolan\Translation\config/locales/fr.json" failed with error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :]
  originalError: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token :],
  moduleName: 'c:\\wamp\\www\\Ayolan\\Translation\\config/locales/fr.json',
  requireModules: [ 'c:\\wamp\\www\\Ayolan\\Translation\\config/locales/fr.json' ],
  fileName: 'c:\\wamp\\www\\Ayolan\\Translation\\config/locales/fr.json' }
```

Comment: It sounds like the JSON file itself has a syntax error.

Comment: THe JSON file itself is fine, I'm sure of it. It seems the issue was coming from the extension, if I do `require(pathLanguages + 'languages');` if finds it and loads it fine... Not sure why...

Comment: if the file changes, you're better off using lang=JSON.parse(FS.readFileSync())

Comment: What version of Node are you running? The error message suggests that the file is being parsed as a JS code block, rather than a JSON file. (i.e., it's the message you get when you have `"string": ...` inside of a code block, `{ ... }`, instead of an object expression)

Comment: Node 0.10.24, added to the main post. That's it, if I try to specify that the file is a .json file then it fails but success if I don't. Weird enough.